# Where does the "CW" in CW-complex come from?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question

I've heard people say that the "CW" in CW-complex comes from the "CW" in JHC Whitehead, though nobody has ever given me a reference for this. Does anyone know where the "CW" in CW-complex comes from?

Comment: This is explained in the third line of the Wikipedia aticle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex

Comment: Haha I don't usually look on Wikipedia for math things :p

Comment: Community Wiki. It means that everyone with more than 100 reputation points in mathematics can edit the complex. :-)

Comment: That's a good one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**C**: "closure-finite"

**W**: "weak topology"

The original source and introduction of the term comes from [Combinatorial homotopy. I](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-03/S0002-9904-1949-09175-9/home.html) by J.H.C. Whitehead, where the abbreviation is explained on the second page. Also, the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex#Formulation).